# Opening two wxt terminals from C++ program

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gnuplot

I have a C++ program, which contains a class method `plot()` working with `gnuplot`:

```
FILE* pipe = popen("/sw/bin/gnuplot -persist","w");
if (pipe != NULL){
    gnuPlotCommand = "load " + scriptFileName + "\n";
    fprintf(pipe, gnuPlotCommand.c_str());
 }
else { ... }
fclose(pipe);
```

Script file itself sets terminal to `wxt` and loads a data file. When I firstly run program calling `obj1.plot()`, a window appears with the plot. If I then run program calling `obj2.plot()` instead (without closing the first window), another window appears, but both windows become "blocked" (I can't rotate plots and can't close the windows). And if I make it

```
obj1.plot();
obj2.plot();
```

only a single plot window appears.

When I launch the same `gnuplot` scripts in the separate `Terminal.app`'s, it works correct (there are two windows and they aren't blocked). How can I achieve it using my program? I have 64-bit Mac OS X 10.8 and XCode in case it matters.

**Update:**

I discovered that deleting `fclose(pipe);` makes two windows appear when `obj1.plot(); obj2.plot();` is called, but one of them is still "blocked".

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation in gnuplot.  It can only have 1 interactive plot open at a time (As far as I know, the same behavior exists with `x11`, `aquaterm`, ...).  If you want to have 2 interactive plots simultaneously, you'll need to spawn a gnuplot process (via `popen`) for each interactive plot you want.

Comment: But I thought I do it anyway - as I call firstly `obj1.plot();` and then `obj2.plot();` (in the same program), and there is `popen` call in `plot()`?

Comment: Actually, I tried it several times and it works sometimes. I think the problem is that XCode runs parallel threads.

Comment: @Victor -- Hmm... I misunderstood your code snippet above.  Yes, it does look like you're using separate pipes now that I understand a bit better.  You closing the pipe will probably result in a non-interactive plot as you noted above.  I'm not sure why this would work sometimes and not others...

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it works sometimes with `fclose(pipe)` eliminated. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the processes running in parallel, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @Victor -- I got that part.  I'm perplexed too ... I don't think that it should have anything to do with the processes running in parallel, but I don't know that much about the details of the `wxt` terminal.